order topology is compact if, and only if, X is a complete reticle.
This is my attempt to make the proof, could someone give some advice/correct it? Please
I have not learned what a complete reticle is, but doing some research, this is the deffinition I got:
$X$ is said to be a complete reticle if every non-empty subset of $X$ that is bounded above has a supremum and infimum.
$\rightarrow$ Let's see that if the order topology is compact, then $X$ is a complete reticle.
Suppose $A\subseteq X$ such that $A\neq \emptyset$ and is bounded above. By hypothesis, it's known that $X$ is totally ordered, so in the subset $A$, there must exist a maximum element, meaning for every $a \in A$, there exists $b$ such that $a\leq b$, thus fulfilling the condition of being bounded above. Furthermore, $A$ will have an infimum $w$ such that $w\leq a$ for every $a\in A$.\newline
Thus, $A$ is an arbitrary subset of $X$ bounded above with supremum and infimum, therefore $X$ is a complete reticle, as this applies to all subsets of $X$.
$\leftarrow$ Let $X$ be a complete reticle with the order topology and $\{U_i\}$ be a covering by open sets of $X$. We know that $X$ is totally ordered, so it's possible to order the elements of the open covering of $X$. Suppose $X$ is not compact, hence, it's not possible to extract a finite subcovering that covers $X$, moreover, for each finite subset of such open covering, there exists $x \in X$ such that $x$ won't be covered by any finite subcovering, thus, let's define $H$ such that $H:=\{x \in X: x$ is not covered$\}$, and $H\neq \emptyset$.\newline
The fact that $X$ is a complete reticle allows to assert that $H$ has a least upper bound (supremum), however, this supremum must be covered by some $u \in \{U_i\}$, since it's an element of $X$, leading to a contradiction regarding the definition of the subset $H$. Therefore, the order topology must be compact.

What is a reticle? Is that the same as a lattice? A complete lattice is usually defined as a partially ordered set in which every subset has a supremum and an infimum. By your definition, the half-open interval $[0,1)$ would be a "complete reticle", although it is not compact.

I think it is the same, but in class we haven´t learned about it. So yes, I would say it is the same as lattice.
